# Formula to get data from other sheet always return lowercase in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet

I have 2 sheets in the excel and I need the First sheet **"Sheet1"** with formulas that involves **"Sheet2"**. (in future sum, rest, etc)
When I tried this

```
$ac = $spreadsheet1->getActiveSheet(0);
$ac->setCellValue('B1', "=Sheet2.B1");
```

It always is converted to **"=sheet2.b1"** *(lowercase in the excel)* and the formula does not work

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try quoting the sheet name, and using `!` to reference the cell:

```
$ac = $spreadsheet1->getActiveSheet(0);
$ac->setCellValue('B1', "='Sheet2'!B1");
```